# How do I import a vector of data in Vensim P.L.E. 8.0.4. x64

Tags: arrays, vector, vensim

I am a user of Vensim P.L.E. 8.0.4. x64. This is the Personal Learning Edition, that is freely available for 60 days.

I am trying to get familiar with it.

I tried to replicate some examples available online, such as these two:

[first video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLVqGquWXYU&t=339s)

[second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JsI9ZYPS54&t=562s)

and I was successful.

Now I would like to include in my simulations not only a scalar, but an array or a vector of numbers. This is because I would like to use a set of real world data I have for different municipalities and it would be of little informative to do it for each of them separately.

I followed the indications provided here:

[Link for the use of the function tabbed array](https://www.vensim.com/documentation/fn_tabbed_array.htm)

which substantially provides what I would need. Yet, at the very same page I read "Availability: Professional and DSS only." I am thus inclined to think that this is not a function I can have access to.

I tried to specify an equation for one of my variables by making use of TABBED ARRAY, but I got the error message "Expecting an operator" in the relevant section of the window, as reported below.

[image: Image of the error message]

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me to understand if the error is related to my sintax, or to the Versim version I am using or to other possible reasons.

I understood, but correct me if I am wrong, that there is a way to work with Vensim by coding but  I am not sure this possibility is open to the version I am using.

I do thank you very much for your help.

Marco

Answer (score 1):

I think that error message really comes from the version PLE you are using.
You also could try import the constants from Excel using the `GET XLS DATA('file','tab','row or col','cell')` function [[1](https://www.vensim.com/documentation/fn_get_xls_data.htm)].  But this function don't work into PLE version too.

So I advise you use [Insight Maker](http://insightmaker.com) in the first steps of modelling, that is general-purpose simulation and modeling tool, open source and that run in your web browser  [[2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1569190X14000513)]. On this platform you could import data manually using converters objects [[3](https://insightmaker.com/converters)].

Below we see a print screen from the [Insight Maker](http://insightmaker.com) workspace with a converter object to data import.
[image: Example converter]

Comment: Yes @Benyamin, they let us do these uploads just in the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

A lookup table is an option. You can paste data from Excel into a lookup.